# Instagram account linked to Facebook, but cross-posting option not showing when creating Facebook Post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, instagram

I have a page on Facebook and it IS linked to Instagram. My Instagram account is a business account and it is also linked to Facebook.

When I try to create a post on Facebook the option to cross-post to Instagram is NOT showing and I don't know why it wouldn't be there if the account IS linked?

What else do I need to do?

I tried posting from Instagram and turned ON the "post to Facebook" and "post to twitter" options. It successfully posted to Twitter, but NOT to the Facebook page.

Linked[image]

Not showing cross-post:

[image: ceb]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the option doesnt appear, but I've found Facebook gives you another integrated tool where you can do it, it's called creator studio.

[Facebook creator studio](https://business.facebook.com/creatorstudio?hc_location=ufi)

There you can create a post from Facebook for Instagram, and checkmark that it also appears in certain Facebook page.

Comment: I'll check this out, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

On one of my FB pages, I had the cross-post option but I just realized today it's missing now. But on my other page, I've never managed to enable the cross-posting option :(, and I set up everything exactly you did.